# Optionally passing arguments to commands in a script

Tags: shell, sh

I've got a shell script with a section like this:

```
if [ "$condition" -eq 1 ]; then
    external_command -argument value1
else
    external_command -argument value1 -second_argument value2
fi
```

I was bugged by this repetition, so I tried this:

```
arg="-second_argument"
val="value2"
if [ "$condition" -eq 1 ]; then
    arg=""
    val=""
fi
external_command -argument value1 "$arg" "$val"
```

It didn't work because the `external_command` still gets the empty strings as distinct arguments and complains.

Is there a way to do this without building the command line repeatedly? In my actual code there are 4 different conditions, so there's a lot of needless repetition.

If I were using Bash, I'd follow [Bash FAQ 050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) and build an array for the command arguments, but I'm not.

Comment: If you are sure that `val` does not contain spaces, you could simply leave out the quotes, but in general, I don't think this can be done  in Pure Posix shell, without reverting to dirty tricks using `eval`.

Comment: I definitely don’t want to look at eval! Sounds like I’m stuck with repeating myself. Or making a Bash script!

Comment: A wise choice. Another possibility is to switch to Zsh, where you can do it without the array trick which is necessary in bash. I personally prefer Zsh over bash, but I am aware that there are also many arguments in favour to bash.

Comment: If switching shells is an option, it doesn't really matter if you use `bash` or `zsh`, as both have arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard workaround is to use the positional parameters in place of an array. Assuming you don't care about the current values:

```
shift $#  # Clear them; optional, as the next line overwrites whatever was there
set -- -argument value1
if [ "$condition" -eq 1 ]; then
  set -- "$@" "-second_argument"  "value2"
fi
external_command "$@"
```

If you *do* care about the current values, run the block in a subshell:

```
(
  set -- -argument value1
  if [ "$condition" -eq 1 ]; then
    set -- "$@" "-second_argument"  "value2"
  fi
  external_command "$@"
)
```

---

Or, define a function, which already has its own set of positional parameters.

```
run_external () {
  condition=$1
  set -- -argument value1
  if [ "$condition" -eq 1 ]; then
    set -- "$@" -second_argument value2
  fi
  external_command "$@"
}

run_external "$condition"
```

Comment: So when I pass `$@` as an argument to the command, it's actually seen as individual arguments?

Comment: Yes; that's the difference between `$@` and `$*`. When quoted, `"$@"` expands to 0 or more distinct words, one per positional argument, while `"$*"` expands to exactly one (possibly empty) word.

Comment: To be clear, `$@` itself isn't passed as an argument; its *expansion* produces 0 or more arguments that are passed.

Answer (score 1):

If you populate a variable whenever the second condition *should be given*, and leave it unset otherwise, you have another POSIX-compliant option:

```
# have a variable set ONLY IF you want the extra arguments passed
if [ "$condition" -eq 1 ]; then
  unset want_extra_args
else
  want_extra_args=1
fi

# and put those arguments in a ${var+val} expansion
external_command -argument value1 ${want_extra_args+-second_argument value2}
```

You can use quotes and other expansions -- which is to say, the following is valid:

```
external_command ... ${want_extra_args+-second_argument "$value2"}
```

Comment: Nice, I thought a lot of those more esoteric expansions were Bash-specific. Apparently not!

Comment: A lot of them are; just got lucky that this particular one that you need isn't.

Answer (score -1):

Just try

```
second=
if [ "$condition" -ne 1 ]; then
    second="-second_argument value2"
fi
external_command -argument value1 $second
```

Note the double quotes / absence of them.
Although user1934428 is right, if you have spaces in value of -second_argument, you might have problems.

Comment: Yes, there are spaces unfortunately!

Comment: Not just spaces, but anything that would contribute to word-splitting (based on the value of `IFS`) or anything that could be expanded as a pattern.

Comment: See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for a detailed explanation of why this practice is generally faulty, and various alternatives thereto.